# How to do scoped external css in vue.js?

Tags: css, vuejs2

I am new to vue.js and saw this video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsoLfELhG74

Which says you can do

```
<style scoped>
</style>
```

to scope the style, but this is if I embed it into the html page. What if I link to a .css file. How could you still scope the css?

Thanks

Comment: You could try using an [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@import) statement. Not sure if that will actually wok but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 14):

You can add a `src` attribute to the style tag like this:

```
<style scoped src="./test.css">
</style>
```

Comment: how does this work? How can it just update the external css and add that attribute filter to that?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking. It doesn't update the external css file. It will make a new css file  based on the external one when you build the project.

Comment: the link `./test.css` is where exactly ? the  `.` refers to node_modules? or where app.js is or where?

Comment: @brahimm this will look in the same directory as the component.

Comment: I can confirm this approach works with Sass (.scss) files as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

first create a scss file like styles/scss/_variables.scss.In that _variables.scss file import your required styles like $bg-color: red;

Next import that scss file in your required .vue file .

```
<style lang="scss">
 @import "../styles/scss/_variables.scss";
 .msg {
        background-color: $bg-color;
      }
</style>
```